# MySQL query with variable data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shortcode

I have searched through various MySQL queries with wildcards, and replace calls, but I can't find exactly what I am looking for.

I need to update shortcodes for an entire site due to a upgrade in the Amazon Product in a Post Plugin.  This string replace call must handle a variable string:

Inside a WordPress database for a mom blog:

I must replace

```
[AMAZONPRODUCT=B0084IG8TM]
```

with

```
[amazon-element asin="B0084IG8TM" fields="title,sm-image,new-price,button"]
```

So the call must identify the base string, and then identify the 10 character product code WHICH IS VARIABLE, and wrap content around that 10 character string inside the square brackets.

Suggestions? 
Thank You Very Much.

Comment: is it always prefixed with `[AMAZONPRODUCT=]` ?

Comment: So you're replacing everything from the start up to and including '=' with '[amazon-element asin="' and you're replacing everything from the end back to ']' with '" fields="title,sm-image,new-price,button"]' ? Yeah, that seems doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your substring (provided its always 10 characters followed by a `]`) like this:

```
select substring(right('[AMAZONPRODUCT=B0084IG8TM]', 11), 1, 10)
```

First it pulls out the last 11 characters using `right()`, and then takes the first 10 characters of that using `substring()`

Which you can then shove the output into a `concat()` call to get your requisite string:

```
select concat('[amazon-element asin="', substring(right('[AMAZONPRODUCT=B0084IG8TM]', 11), 1, 10), '" fields="title,sm-image,new-price,button"]')
```

You can then build an update query to be something like this:

```
update <your_table>
  set your_field = concat('[amazon-element asin="', substring(right('[AMAZONPRODUCT=B0084IG8TM]', 11), 1, 10), '" fields="title,sm-image,new-price,button"]')
  where your_field like '[AMAZONPRODUCT=%'
```

Okay, so it can be anywhere in the string, so long as it is only ONCE in the string, it is still relatively simple. If it can be in the string more than once, forget about doing it with a query and do it with a php script or something. (or run the update multiple times, until all occurrences are changed)

```
update wp_posts
  set post_content = concat(left(post_content, locate('[AMAZONPRODUCT=', post_content) -1), '[amazon-element asin="',substring(post_content, locate('[AMAZONPRODUCT=', post_content) + 15, 10), '" fields="title,sm-image,new-price,button"]', substring(post_content, locate('[AMAZONPRODUCT=', post_content) + 26)) 
  where post_content like '%[AMAZONPRODUCT=%'
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e1aab/9)

Comment: hmm, the entire [AMAZONPRODUCT=XXXXXXXXXX] is actually part of a much larger string, (an entire wordpress post) so this didn't do anything:

update wp_posts set post_content = concat('[amazon-element asin="', substring(right('[AMAZONPRODUCT=B0084IG8TM]', 11), 1, 10), '" fields="title,sm-image,new-price,button"]') where post_content like '[AMAZONPRODUCT=%'

**Apologies**, I should have been clearer.

this query did not search inside of the larger post, nor re-add the rest of the full string... :)

Comment: this is what happens when you don't describe the full problem in the question. how many times can the string appear in a post? once only, or more than once?

Comment: @mttorley updated. as i said in the answer, if it can appear in the post more than once, it wont work - (well it might if you run the query multiple times, it should catch one instance of the string each time)

Comment: I've been informed that it can happen more than once in the long post string. Apologies for the hassle, but no worries on the multiple times,.. ah the extra wild card, i see. let me try

Comment: @mttorley more than an extra wildcard, now it has to find the thing in the content as well. anyway should have better results

Comment: Thank you Pala, I tried this on a dummy database, and multiple calls to this SQL query did the trick.  Thank you very much from this newbie.

Comment: @mttorley no problem. since it worked can you click the accept answer tick mark next to the votes?